# Azure DevOps API responds with "Object moved" page using access token obtained with OAuth 2.0 flow with Azure Entra ID app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

**MY SETUP**:

1. I have created a multi-tenant app in Azure Active Directory. I have added two scopes in **"API permissions"** tab for this App registration for **Azure DevOps** API: `user_impersonation` and `vso.profile`.

   [image: here is the screenshot example of my scopes]
2. I have implemented the OAuth2 auth code flow:

   1. I use the next URL for authorization:

      ```
      https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
      response_type=code
      &client_id=<MY_APP_CLIENT_ID>
      &scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2Fuser_impersonation%20https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2Fvso.profile
      &redirect_uri=<MY_REDIRECT_URI>
      ```

      Note, I use the same scopes in query params as I have configured in the app:
      `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation`
      `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.profile`

      And additional `offline_access` scope to receive `refresh_token`  in `/token` response.
   2. I use the next URL for code (to token) exchange:
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
   3. After exchanging the code for a token, I receive a pair of access/refresh tokens with the next scopes:

      ```
       https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.code_full
       https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.code_status
       https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.code_write
       https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.profile 
       https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.project
      ```

**PROBLEM**:

I am trying to fetch [Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and other Azure DevOps Repos API like [Repositories List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) or [Commit details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).
But I always receive a response with status **302** and an HTML page with the title **Object moved**.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. Have I missed something during app registration, or have I missed some parameters in OAuth2 flows?
2. When I try to do the same flow, but use this scopes instead:
   `offline_access 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`
   I can make API calls and retrieve data from Azure API with 200 status code. Is it some bug? As I can see numbers `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` means resource id `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com`.
3. When I use credentials for users from another tenant - I get the error right after typing the user email and hitting the **Next** button:
   `This username may be incorrect. Make sure you typed it correctly. Otherwise, contact your admin.`   How can I make it work with users
   from another tenant?
4. Should I use legacy [Azure DevOps OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/azure-devops-oauth?view=azure-devops) to access Azure DevOps API instead of [Microsoft Entra ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/architecture/auth-oauth2) app?

Answer (score 0):

For Q1&Q2: “499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798” is a unique scope identifier of Azure DevOps API resource. The `scope` for the token should be `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` which provides access to Azure DevOps Services REST API. It's not a bug.

For Q3: According to the error message, it seems that there’s a problem with your account and license. Please check if you can access your Azure Entra ID using this affected account and if there is any MFA.

For Q4: It's suggested that new app developers should use Microsoft Entra ID OAuth to integrate with Azure DevOps, according to [his doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/azure-devops-oauth?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=This%20information%20is%20for%20existing%20Azure%20DevOps%20OAuth%20apps%20only.%20New%20app%20developers%20should%20use%20Microsoft%20Entra%20ID%20OAuth%20to%20integrate%20with%20Azure%20DevOps.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Q1: Regarding `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`. I can not find information that I need to use this scope in the Azure documentation :(

Comment: Q3: I also tried to pass the OAuth2 flow with the account not connected to Entra ID. I can not find any information in docs that Azure organization should be connected to Azure ID to use OAuth2 flow.

Comment: Q1: You can see the related info from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=powershell#:~:text=The%20scope%20for%20the%20token%20should%20be%20499b84ac%2D1321%2D427f%2Daa17%2D267ca6975798/.default%20which%20provides%20access%20to%20Azure%20DevOps%20Services%20REST%20API.).

Comment: I can not understand why this scope works when Azure Documentation said that almost all endpoints for Azure DevOps require a `vso.code_write` scope.

Comment: The `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` is the App ID of Azure DevOps. The scope can also be requested like `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/{requiredScope}`, for example, `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/vso.build`.  `vso.code_write` grants the ability to read, update, and delete source code, access metadata about commits, changesets, branches, and other version control artifacts. Also grants the ability to create and manage pull requests and code reviews and to receive notifications about version control events via service hooks.

Comment: The `.default` scope is used to refer generically to a resource service (API) in a request, without identifying specific permissions. If consent is necessary, using `.default` signals that consent should be prompted for all required permissions listed in the application registration (for all APIs in the list). See more info about the `.default` scope from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scopes-oidc#the-default-scope).